# Where is the canonical location for the BBDB manual?

Tags: bbdb

It seems development has been spread around over the years. The EmacsWiki still points to the manual on SourceForge but it seems very out of date. Configuration variables mentioned in the manual are no longer available in my MELPA installed package. Is there a more upto date version online?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manual for BBDBv2 → http://obbdb.sourceforge.net/#manual

Manual for BBDBv3 → **does not exist**.

FWIW here are some BBDBv3 resources:

- **Discussion about (missing) BBDBv3 manual on official mailing list**: https://www.mail-archive.com/bbdb-info%40lists.sourceforge.net/msg05487.html
- Official BBDBv3 project page: https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/bbdb/
- Configuration example: http://blog.petitepomme.net/post/28547901478/installing-and-configuring-bbdb-3
- Tool to synchronize BBDBv3 (and v2) with your Google Contacts, MS Outlook, CardDAV: http://asynk.io/

Here is my setup based on the latest code (because it adds support for mu4e) obtained with `git clone git://git.savannah.nongnu.org/bbdb.git` (should be also available on MELPA):

```el
(use-package bbdb-loaddefs
  :commands bbdb
  :config
  (bbdb-initialize 'gnus
           ;;bbdb-insinuate-gnus adds bindings for the default
           ;;keys to Gnus and configures Gnus to notify the
           ;;BBDB when new messages are loaded. This
           ;;notification is required if the BBDB is to be
           ;;able to display BBDB entries for messages
           ;;displayed in Gnus.

           'message
           ;; bbdb-insinuate-message adds a binding for M-TAB
           ;; to Message mode. This will enable completion of
           ;; addressees based on BBDB records.

           'mu4e
           'anniv)

  (bbdb-mua-auto-update-init 'gnus 'message 'mu4e)

  ;; size of the bbdb popup
  (setq bbdb-mua-pop-up-window-size 1)

  ;; how to handle new entries
  ;; (setq bbdb-mua-update-interactive-p '(query . create))

  ;; look at every address; not only the first one
  ;; (setq bbdb-message-all-addresses t)

  (setq bbdb-phone-style 'nil)

  ;; http://www.emacs.uniyar.ac.ru/doc/em24h/emacs183.htm
  (use-package bbdb-gnus
    :config
    (setq bbdb/gnus-score-default 1000)
    (setq gnus-score-find-score-files-function
          '(gnus-score-find-bnews bbdb/gnus-score))))
```

Answer (score 1):

The canonical location of the BBDBv3 manual is in the [source repo of BBDBv3](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bbdb.git) at the savannah project page, i.e. at http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bbdb.git/tree/doc/bbdb.texi

Comment: The linked page does seem a bit of an empty placeholder.

Comment: Not the canonical manual, but it hasn't been mentioned yet so I thought I should say there is a good manual as one might expect for an emacs package, [here](https://github.com/andycowl/bbdb3-manual).